# SAS - Using Global Normalization Factor w/o Using Macro Variable

Tags: macros, sas, global

Disclaimer: This is mostly a style/best practices question as I do have a functional solution using a macro variable (outlined below) and thus may be inappropriate for this site.

Given a dataset of non-normalized risk scores, e.g.:

Dataset_1:

```
Person, Score
A, 1.00
B, 4.00
C, 2.35
...
```

I would like to normalize such that the arithmetic average is 1.0.  I could summarize this dataset, developing the average risk score and divide each observation by that risk score. For example:

Proc Summary ....; yielding the dataset with one observation:

Dataset_2:

```
Avg_Score
2.5
```

Then use:

```
Data _null_; Set Dataset_2;
  Call Symput("NormFactor", Avg_Score);
Run;
```

And:

```
Data NormalizedScores;
  Set Dataset_1;
  Score_Norm = Score / &NormFactor.;
Run;
```

However, this seems like trash code to me.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the old fashioned way, there is a better way than the macro variable; just merge the datasets, or else set them if there's just one mean.  (Merge if you have a BY variable.)

For example:

```
data dataset_1;
input Person $ Score;
datalines;
A 1.00
B 4.00
C 2.35
;
run;
proc means data=dataset_1 noprint;
  var score;
  output out=dataset_2 mean=avg_score;
run;


Data NormalizedScores;
  set dataset_1;
  if _n_=1 then set dataset_2;
  Score_Norm = Score / avg_score;
Run;
```

Variables that come from a `SET` statement are retained automatically, and since we only read in the second dataset once, they're not replaced or set to missing.

The more slick way would be to use [PROC STDIZE](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_stdize_sect012.htm), which is the newer version of `PROC STANDARD`, but it's not clear to me if there's a particular method that does precisely what you want.

Comment: `STDIZE` is part of SAS/STAT and `PROC STANDARD` is in Base.  I tend to use STANDARD because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `PROC STANDARD`

```
data test;
input Person $ Score;
datalines;
A 1.00
B 4.00
C 2.35
;

proc standard data=test out=test2 mean=1;
var Score;
run;
```

Comment: I would like to have the scores multiplicatively normalized.  I wasn't aware of the "standard" procedure, though.  I see that I could log transform and use this method, but am I missing an option to do this in a more slick way with this procedure?

Comment: I don't think so.  The log transform is probably your best bet.  There might be another procedure to do this, but I cannot think of one.  I would write a macro to do this and just use it when needed.